# Should headers used as part of a base class interface be included in the derived class

Tags: c++

Take the following example:

```
// base.h
#include <string>
struct base
{
    virtual ~base() = default;
    virtual void do_something(const std::string& arg) const = 0;
};

// derived.h
struct derived : base
{
    void do_something(const std::string& arg) const
    {
         //...
    }
};
```

In this example should `derived.h` include the `string` header?

I fully agree with the principle of including what you use but in this case `base.h` has to include `string` and if the interface changes to not use `string` (and the `include <string>` is accordingly removed from `base.h`) then the interface will break highlighting anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the interface changes not to include `string`, your derived `do_something` will have to change as well. If you need  in the `derived.h` *independently* of the interface (e.g. due to details unrelated to interface but present in the implementation) - in this case yes, it's valid and probably preferable to include `<string>` there as well.

Comment: I like the idea of including it if it's used independent of the interface. Nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

I take the approach of *always `include`ing anything I need for **that** file*. I then don't have to go around hunting through headers and untangling webs of dependencies when I'm missing a symbol somewhere. Include guards mean that this is cheap.

But it's completely up to you. If you want to omit it, to make `derived.cpp` shorter, and add it in at a later date if the need arises, that's fine too.

There's simply no "right" answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can include "base.h". Don't think too much.The less code you write,the better your code is.

```
#include "base.h"
struct derived :public base
{
    void do_something(const std::string& arg) const
    {
         //...
    }
};
```